# Transition on parent view overrides animation in a child view (Button)

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-animation

I have the following view I place inside a button's label:

```
struct ButtonLoading: View {
    @Binding var isAnimating: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 4) {
            CircleView(isAnimating: $isAnimating, idx: 0)
            CircleView(isAnimating: $isAnimating, idx: 1)
            CircleView(isAnimating: $isAnimating, idx: 2)
        }
    }
}

struct CircleView: View {
    @Binding var isAnimating: Bool
    var idx: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(Color.white)
            .frame(width: 4, height: 4)
            .offset(y: isAnimating ? -4 : 0)
            .animation(Animation.spring(response: 0.6, dampingFraction: 1.0, blendDuration: 1.0)
                        .repeatForever(autoreverses: true)
                        .delay(Double(idx) * 0.25))
    }
}
```

then the following views:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var current: String = "one"
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red.opacity(0.05).ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack {
                if current == "one" {
                    ViewOne()
                        .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
                }
                if current == "two" {
                    ViewTwo()
                        .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                withAnimation {
                    self.current = "two"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ViewOne: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.blue.ignoresSafeArea()
            Text("View One")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    }
}

struct ViewTwo: View {
    @State var isAnimating = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white.ignoresSafeArea()
            
            Button(action: {
                isAnimating = true
            }) {
                ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                    ButtonLoading(isAnimating: $isAnimating)
                        .opacity(isAnimating ? 1 : 0)
                    
                    Text("Continue")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .opacity(isAnimating ? 0 : 1)
                }
                .frame(height: 44)
                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                .background(Color.blue)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I click on the button, the expected behavior is to see the button's content change to the ellipsis loading animation (with the dots moving up and down, repeatedly). This works just fine if I remove the `.transition(.move(edge: .trailing))` attached to `ViewTwo`. However, in its current state, it appears that the transition animation clobbers the button animation. I see it moving in and out from the trailing edge. Any ideas? SwiftUI is driving me nuts!

**Update:**

Found another answer from a year ago that the prolific, Asperi, contributed to. Wrapping my button in one of these does solve the problem:

```
struct HelperView<Content: View> : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var content: () -> Content
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIHostingController<Content> {
        UIHostingController(rootView: content())
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ host: UIHostingController<Content>, context: Context) {
        host.rootView = content() // Update content
    }
}
```

Is this the only way to solve this?

**Update 2**

Switching to opacity instead of offset and adding an `.animation(nil)` resolves the issue with the animation inheriting the parent transition:

```
struct CircleView: View {
    @Binding var isAnimating: Bool
    var idx: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(Color.white)
            .frame(width: 4, height: 4)
            .animation(nil)
            .opacity(isAnimating: 0 : 1)
            .animation(Animation.spring(response: 0.6, dampingFraction: 1.0, blendDuration: 1.0)
                        .repeatForever(autoreverses: true)
                        .delay(Double(idx) * 0.25))
    }
}
```

However, adding a custom `GeometryEffect` to change the offset does not work. Furthermore, adding a `.transition(.identity)` with and without `.animation(nil)` also doesn't work. Trying everything here. =)